# Which technique should work to change a tumblr theme background?

Tags: css, themes, customization, background-image, tumblr

I'm baffled.  This should be rudimentary for me, but I have to admit, nothing has worked so far.  I have a tumblr log (http://tropedart.tumblr.com) and I am trying to use an image as a background in an already existing theme.  The image is stored both on my server in a public folder and on tumblr's servers.  Here's what I've tried:

I've edited the custom HTML with the following:

`<body style="background-image: url('http://russellbits.com/public-images/bkgd-page.jpg') fixed top left repeat;">`

I've edited the custom CSS with:

`body { background-image: url('http://russellbits.com/public-images/bkgd-page.jpg') fixed top left repeat; }`

I've *also* tried to use the template tags in the custom CSS:

`background: {color:Background} url(‘{image:http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_mcs0mnVfx71rsijsso1_400.jpg}’) top left fixed repeat;`

None of these efforts have succeeded. I'm almost embarrassed to ask, because this is simple CSS stuff that I know all too well. But what can I say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your theme uses an unintuitive method to set the background image. Instead of a proper background image, there's just a big element stretched over the entire page.

Take a look at line `127` of your stylesheet:

```
.noise {
    background: #EEEEEE url("http://static.tumblr.com/xcxngn2/Iz0ld1v2h/bg.png") repeat;
}
```

To override this style, just put this CSS into your custom stylesheet:

```
.noise {
    background: #EEEEEE url("http://russellbits.com/public-images/bkgd-page.jpg") repeat;
}
```

Comment: Wow! Worked like a charm instantly.  Thanks so much, it would have taken me the rest of the day and maybe tomorrow to figure that out. I wonder why they built it like that?

Comment: That'd be a good question for the person who designed this theme. I'm not sure why they did it this way.